# string.format doesn't work on strings

Tags: c#

Uhm, so I have run into this before. I want to do this.

```
 PhoneNumber = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", compView.PHONE_NUMBER),
```

BUT! compView.PHONE_NUMBER is already a string :( so it doesn't work. my first thought was to create an extension method but then I thought maybe I would put this out to people and see if someone out in the community had any better suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `compView.PHONE_NUMBER`?

Comment: Yes, I tried and played with the suggestions first before I accepted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your phone number a string, you can try

```
PhoneNumber =  string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}",
                  compView.PHONE_NUMBER.Substring(0, 3),
                  compView.PHONE_NUMBER.Substring(3, 3),
                  compView.PHONE_NUMBER.Substring(6, 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert it first then if it's just a string of a number:

```
PhoneNumber = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(compView.PHONE_NUMBER));
```

Also you had a comma at the end, did you mean to have a semicolon?

Comment: He could be initializing multiple variables in a single statement, hence the comma.

Comment: the convention is:
NPA-NXX-XXXX

NPA is the number plan area. Area code. the first digit is always a 2 thru 9
NXX is the central office. the firstdigit is always 2-9
XXXX can be any digit -- so unless it's an invalid number, but he should be checking for validity somewhere else in his application

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS!  Phone Numbers are not numbers they are strings.  IF you try to convert 8181235555 to Int32 you'll see the problem.

Comment: @rtalbot - what do you mean? He's obviously passing in a string value, and this string holds all numeric characters, why wouldn't you be able to convert this to an integer? - His goal is to format a STRING made up of numeric CHARACTERS to another STRING formatted differentley - and I'm saying if you convert it from "8181235555" to 8181235555, his format will make that NUMBER 8181235555 = "818-123-5555"

Comment: The example (8181235555) is out of the range of Int32 as would be many other valid phone numbers.  Convert.ToInt32 will throw an exception. If you would never perform numeric operations on it (adding, subtracting, etc) then it is a string and not a number (even if it is a numeric string).

Comment: I believe you are correct. See my edited response. Use a long (Int64)

Comment: Yeah.  While the likelihood of a phone number ever exceeding the bounds of Int64 is extremely low.  I would still keep phone number as a string.  This problem is easy enough to solve with substrings, etc.

Comment: Thanks all, yes, it is in a select new vendor { a =1, y = 2, etc... statement.

Comment: So yeah - I just don't like converting things that aren't used as numbers ever so I went with Bala R's suggestion

Comment: Fair enough. Just another way to do it :)